# Three.js - Last bunch of points are not being rendered

Tags: javascript, three.js, lidar

The last bunch points are not being rendered in the THREE.js viewer despite the BufferGeometry object containing all relevant data. I am using version 85 of the THREE.js library (some points are missing) and if I revert to using version 67 all points display fine.

In version 67 I use THREE.Float32Attribute and THREE.ParticleSystem and all points load fine.

In version 85 I am using THREE.Float32BufferAttribute and THREE.Points (due to deprecation of the older functions).  I receive no errors, it is just that I can clearly see the points are missing (whole patch/area of them).  The missing bunch of points are the last points to be read from the LiDAR file - I know this as I use LAStools lasview.exe to view the file and this tool loads the points in order of being read - not sure if this has something to do with why THREE.js is missing the last points to be added/rendered.

I have debugged the code to ensure I am passing values as expected into the THREE.Float32BufferAttribute constructor and assigning the expected values to the array.  When creating the THREE.Points constructor, I can see no issue with the values passed (a buffer geometry object and a shader material object).  I can see no alternative to using the THREE.Points object as the THREE.ParticleSystem is no longer used.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var data = [an array of data];
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute((pointCount), 3));
geometry.getAttribute('position').array = new Float32Array(data);
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
...
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(...);
var particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, shaderMaterial);
particles.name = geometry.name;
...
this.scene.add(particles);
this.scene.needsUpdate = true;
```

No errors at all. As stated, works fine using version 67 but there are missing points when using version 85.

The following is the version 67 code that works fine:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var data = [an array of data];
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32Attribute((pointCount), 3)); // Using Float32Attribute instead of Float32BufferAttribute
geometry.getAttribute('position').array = new Float32Array(data);
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
...
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(...);
var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, shaderMaterial); // Using ParticleSystem instead of Points
particles.name = geometry.name;
...
this.scene.add(particles);
this.scene.needsUpdate = true;
```

I have added screen shots. The first image is using version 85 and the code above.  The second image is the same data being loaded into version 67 (ignore the difference in the intensity colour as the purpose of the image is to show the missing patch on the right hand side which is the last of the data in the BufferGeometry array)

[version 85 missing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDmgQ.png)

[version 67 all points rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLAZo.png)

Comment: **1.** `ParticleSystem` was renamed `Points`. They are the same thing. **2.** `Float32(Buffer)Attribute` is just a helper wrapped around `BufferAttribute`. Try creating your attributes with: `new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array(data), stride )` **3.** r85 is 20 versions old. Are you unable to upgrade to the latest (r106)? **4.** Can you generate some uniform particle data such that you can verify the newer version actually _stops_ rendering after a certain number of particles? At what index does it stop?

Comment: @TheJim01.  Number 2 recommendation has fixed the issue.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheJim01 I have resolved this as follows:

```
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(classificationGeometry.positions), 3));
```

instead of declaring/setting the objects separately.